# Limit connections to private network with firewalld and wireguard in point to site

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, firewalld, wireguard, point-to-site-vpn

I am trying to limit VPN access to a private network running in Openstack. The wireguard server is inside the private network and the traffic is routed to its private ip address from Openstack.
Inside the private network is a Dns Server all clients need to reach and for each client a specific server. The clients should only reach their specific server and the dns server.
Administrators should also access the private network via wireguard without limitation using a different wireguard interface.

### Network

**Wireguard Server(Ubuntu 22.04)**:

- `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` set in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
- ens3: 10.10.10.107
- wg_admin: 10.42.43.1 / Port 51821
- wg_clients: 10.42.42.1 / Port 51820

**Servers inside the private Network**:

- DNS Server: 10.10.10.203
- Client1 Server: 10.10.10.133
- Client2 Server: 10.10.10.209

**Connecting clients/admins**:

- Client1: 10.42.42.3
- Client2: 10.42.42.2
- Admin1: 10.42.43.2

### Wireguard Server Config

I am using two zones:
**public**: Handling the incoming traffic

```bash
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens3
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh ssh-custom
  ports: 51821/udp 51820/udp
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

**wireguard**: Handling the wireguard traffic; limiting which traffic forwarding

```bash
$ firewall-cmd --zone=wireguard --list-all
wireguard (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wg_admin wg_clients
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.42.42.2" destination address="10.10.10.209" masquerade
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.42.42.2" destination address="10.10.10.203" masquerade
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.42.42.3" destination address="10.10.10.203" masquerade
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.42.43.0/24" masquerade log prefix="wg_admin_masq" level="warning"
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.42.42.3" destination address="10.10.10.133" masquerade
```

### Problem

With the current firewalld setup i would assume that packets coming in on the wiregurad interfaces are handled in the wireguard zone. When a rich rule is matching the source ip should be changed to the wireguard server ip `10.10.10.107` and then simply routed to the client. But unfortunately this is not working like this.

When checking the kernel messages I see:

```bash
[Thu Jun  8 13:32:18 2023] "filter_FWD_wireguard_REJECT: "IN=wg_admin OUT=ens3 MAC= SRC=10.42.43.2 DST=10.10.10.203 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=31157 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=44920 DPT=53 WINDOW=64860 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[Thu Jun  8 13:32:20 2023] "filter_FWD_wireguard_REJECT: "IN=wg_clients OUT=ens3 MAC= SRC=10.42.42.2 DST=10.10.10.203 LEN=82 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=9462 PROTO=UDP SPT=36905 DPT=53 LEN=62 
[Thu Jun  8 13:32:23 2023] "filter_FWD_wireguard_REJECT: "IN=wg_admin OUT=ens3 MAC= SRC=10.42.43.2 DST=10.10.10.203 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=50271 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55930 DPT=53 WINDOW=64860 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[Thu Jun  8 13:32:41 2023] "filter_FWD_wireguard_REJECT: "IN=wg_clients OUT=ens3 MAC= SRC=10.42.42.2 DST=10.10.10.203 LEN=92 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=2910 PROTO=UDP SPT=45837 DPT=53 LEN=72 
[Thu Jun  8 13:32:41 2023] "filter_FWD_wireguard_REJECT: "IN=wg_clients OUT=ens3 MAC= SRC=10.42.42.2 DST=10.10.10.203 LEN=92 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=58612 PROTO=UDP SPT=53142 DPT=53 LEN=72
```

My custom log prefix is not shown so I assume my rich rules are ignored.
When I try to ping the dns server:

```
$ ping 10.10.10.203
PING 10.10.10.203 (10.10.10.203) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.42.43.1 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
```

When I try to ping the wireguard server:

```
$ ping 10.10.10.107
PING 10.10.10.107 (10.10.10.107) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.107: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=26.7 ms
$ ping 10.42.42.1  
PING 10.42.42.1 (10.42.42.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.42.42.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=28.5 ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer my self. The feature allowing routing and filtering with firewalld is called policies and [was introduced later](https://firewalld.org/2020/09/policy-objects-introduction). This [great post from Pro Custodibus](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2022/04/firewalld-access-control-for-wireguard/) also explains different scenarios using wireguard and firewalld.

With policies it is possible to route traffic from one zone to another and to set a specific rule set for the traffic passing through.

To archive the separation between my wireguard interfaces/connections for admins/clients and routing into the private network the wireguard server we:

- split up the wireguard interfaces into separate zones
- added a zone were the traffic is forwared
- added two policies which connecting the wireguard zones with the forward zone
- added rules to the policies to filter the wireguard traffic

### Zones:

```
$ firewall-cmd --info=zone=wg_clients
wg_clients (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wg_clients
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:

$ firewall-cmd --info=zone=wg_admins
wg_admins (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wg_admins
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:

$ firewall-cmd --info=zone=forward
forward (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 10.10.10.0/24
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

### Policies:

```
$ firewall-cmd --info-policy=wg_clients2forward
wg_clients2forward (active)
  priority: -1
  target: REJECT
  ingress-zones: wg_clients
  egress-zones: forward
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
        rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.10.10.203" service name="dns" accept
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.42.42.3/32" destination address="10.10.10.133" service name="https" accept
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.42.42.2/32" destination address="10.10.10.209" service name="https" accept

$ firewall-cmd --info-policy=wg_admins2forward
wg_admins2forward (active)
  priority: -1
  target: REJECT
  ingress-zones: wg_admins
  egress-zones: forward
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
        rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.10.10.0/24" accept
```